# Changing div position with css on hover

Tags: html, css

In the following code, I want to keep the `.link1` and `.link2` hidden, and on hover over the `.image`, I want make them visible with the transition effect so that the `link1` moves from the left and `link2` moves from the right and they both come to the center of the div.

I am trying following code, but it does not work:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="image"><img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8043/8357588952_94cee71fef.jpg" /></div>
  <div class="hover">
     <a class="link1">Link 1</a>
     <a class="link2">Link 2</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrap{
  margin: 100px;
  width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.image{
  border: 1px solid red;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s; 
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s; 
    transition: all 0.4s;
}

.hover{
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;  
}

.link1{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 70px;
    height: 30px;
    background: yellow; 
     position: absolute;
     left: -100%;
}

.image:hover .link1{
   left: 40%;  
}

.link2{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 70px;
    height: 30px;
    background: yellow; 
     position: absolute;
     right: -100%;
}

.image:hover .link2{
   right: 40%;  
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/XjTyJ/

Comment: Something like this? : http://jsfiddle.net/XjTyJ/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a lot of bad selectors going on.

I changed the `.image:hover` selectors to `.hover:hover` as the `<a>` elements were children of the `.hover` div.

I also changed the `.image` selector that has the animation rules to `.hover a` to apply the animations to the anchors within.

I think that you misunderstand how some CSS rules work. When you want an element to sit within another, you must tell it to fill 100% of its parent using width and height : 100%.

The way you had it, the .hover div was sat underneath the image div. All's well now though.

```
.wrap{
  margin: 100px;
  width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.hover a{
  border: 1px solid red;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s; 
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s; 
    transition: all 0.4s;
}

.hover{
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

a.link1{
    width: 70px;
    height: 30px;
    background: yellow; 
     position: absolute;
  left: -100%;
}

.hover:hover a.link1{
   left: 40%;  
}

a.link2{
    width: 70px;
    height: 30px;
    background: yellow; 
     position: absolute;
  right: -100%;
}

.hover:hover a.link2{
   right: 40%;  
}
```

:)

As a last note: when you set an element's position it effectivley assigns `display: block;` to it so the `display: inline-block;` was pretty much useless. :)
http://jsfiddle.net/XjTyJ/1/